# How can i fetch the buffer image from mongodb on ejb page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

Storing data like follow in monogo db like as follow below

```
 _id:5a43366cf6e0443e3c782181
 coin_code:abc
 wallet_balance:000000
 wallet_name:xyz
 image:Object
    contentType:image/png   
    data:Binary('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEhUSEhMV')
__v:0
```

fetching inage on ejs page

```
 <% var i=1 %>
 <% result.forEach(function(result){ %>                                
<tr class="odd gradeX">
 <td><%= i++ %></td>
 <td><span class="chat-img pull-left"><img src="<%=  result.image.data %>" alt="Coin Image" class="img-circle"></span></td>
 <td><%= result.wallet_name %></td>
 <td><%= result.wallet_balance %></td>
 <td><%= result.coin_code %></td>
</tr>
```

but according to above code i am not getting image i am getting output like this-

+�� )�p�&�
JH�Ʒ?�7ӏ)-����v�Z֥����J@�k�f��u�L��Ԅ�|�+g�g��y{4��uŏ��a���ȍȪ�FG@�)^��
R������������p��5�Xide&y&Y�I$#��#f�g�!�F����a���Ƹ_Y̱3i6�2�_¥�(�1�x�mӿ��'�Iޔ~(�����܎̃��΃d��f�Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I store images as strings in Base64 format.

Example: 
`"image" : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAN0..."`

Then I show images on EJS pages like the below:

Example: 
`<img id="image" src=<%- image %>>`

Hope this helps...

Comment: in this case how would be my schema,could u please guide me.

Comment: I think you have 3 choices. First off, if you create your data field as Base64 binary data, you might combine it with contentType data to use in EJS just like me (ex: `<img id="image" src="data:<%- image.contentType %>>;base64,"<%- image.data %>`). Secondly, you might compund your fileds to get proper Base64 form when querying from MongoDB. Thirdly, you might change your `image` field as String. However, the all three choices are valid if contentType data is not important for you.

Comment: Also you might use any 'base64 online converter' you found to test your image data by googling it..

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i am successfully did with third choice.